# Errors with sentinel-controlled loop/switch

Tags: c++

A mail order house sells five different products whose retail prices
are: product 1 — $2.98, product 2—$4.50, product 3—$9.98, product 4—$4.49 and product 5—
$6.87. Write a program that reads a series of pairs of numbers as follows:
a) product number
b) quantity sold
Your program should use a switch statement to determine the retail price for each product. Your
program should calculate and display the total retail value of all products sold. Use a sentinel-controlled loop to determine when the program should stop looping and display the final results.

I get tons of error when I try to compile my code and I was wondering what I did wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numberOfProducts = 0;
int costOfProducts = 0;
int productTotal = 0;
double amountP1 = 0;
double amountP2 = 0;
double amountP3 = 0;
double amountP4 = 0;
double amountP5 = 0;
double product1 = 2.98;
double product2 = 4.50;
double product3 = 9.98;
double product4 = 4.49;
double product5 = 6.87;
cout<<"How many products do you want to buy? -1 to finish shopping"<<endl;
cin>>numberOfProducts;
while(numberOfProducts != -1)
     cout<<"Which products do you want to buy? -1 to finish shopping"<<endl;
     cin>>costOfProducts;
        switch(costOfProducts)
     {
        case product1:
            cout<<"Product 1($2.98) has been purchased";
                productTotal = productTotal + 2.98;
                amountP1 = amountP1 + 1;
                break;
        case product2:
            cout<<"Product 2($4.50) has been purchased";
                productTotal = productTotal + 4.50;
                amountP2 = amountP2 + 1;
                break;
        case product3:
            cout<<"Product 3($9.98) has been purchased";
                productTotal = productTotal + 9.98;
                amountP3 = amountP3 + 1;
                break;
        case product4:
            cout<<"Product 4($4.49) has been purchased";
                productTotal = productTotal + 4.49;
                amountP4 = amountP4 + 1;
                break;
        case product5:
            cout<<"Product 5($6.87) has been purchased";
            productTotal = productTotal + 6.87;
            amountP5 = amountP5 + 1;
                break;
        default:
            cout<<"Sorry, please select a product"; << endl;

     }

     cout<<"The total amount of products bought are: " << numberOfProducts;
     cout<<"The total amount of product 1's bought is: $" << amountP1 << endl;
     cout<<"The total amount of product 2's bought is: $" << amountP2 << endl;
     cout<<"The total amount of product 3's bought is: $" << amountP3 << endl;
     cout<<"The total amount of product 4's bought is: $" << amountP4 << endl;
     cout<<"The total amount of product 5's bought is: $" << amountP5 << endl;
     cout<<"The total price of all your products are: $" << productTotal << endl;
     return 0;
```

}

Comment: _'I get tons of error ...'_ Read thoroughly what the compiler is telling you, and solve them one by one (the amount of follow up errors will usually reduce with this process).

Comment: Why do you declare `product1` through `product5` and not use them?  BTW, they should be declared as `const` and replace the magic numbers in your `productTotal` assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolons at the end of the following lines:

- `while(numberOfProducts != -1);`
- `switch(costOfProducts);`

In addition, the compiler doesn't understand the following symbols (and neither do I):

- `product1`
- `product2`
- `product3`
- `product4`
- `product5`

BTW, I strongly recommend that you add a couple of `cin>>` there, if you actually want this to work...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but It still doesn't work. In the original it had no ; in while and switch(). I was just testing to see if it made any difference. I did the the first cout without cin because I think it would work in the while()loop since it's adding 1 every an item is purchased so technically it should be the same even if I put cin. For the switch() I don't really understand how it works. I'm assuming it works now unless I need to use cin with the 2nd cout.

Comment: @RiotPhreak Follow my advice I gave in the comment to your question! We're not a swarm-intelligence online compiler/debugging service here!!

Comment: @barak-manos You're replicating the process I've been describing quite well here ;) ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: LOL, good one. I was just asking myself, why have I answered this question in the first place... I'm probably a little bored, and should really find better things to do with myself... c ya :)

Comment: I'm a beginner don't really understand most of the errors unless it's the basic ones. "IntelliSense: "Cout" is ambiguous" how the hell do I fix that. 2) "Warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Comment: @RiotPhreak Don't care about _'Intellisense'_ and _'Warning'_ in the 1st place, concentrate on compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about statement blocks.

```
while(numberOfProducts != -1)
     cout<<"Which products do you want to buy? -1 to finish shopping"<<endl;
     cin>>costOfProducts;
```

I'll play a game with you.  You need to insert `{` to begin a statement block and `}` to end one.
Your role is to figure out where they go.

Hint 1:  The expression inside a `while` statement applies to the statement block.

Hint 2:  One or more statements can be placed in a statement block.

If you wish to cheat, you can look up the syntax of the `while` statement, for multiple statements in the loop.

Comment: Hey man! What you're going to argue about? That's [Apple style](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2014/02/gotofail/), not good enough for you??